# Loop creating infinite grep process

Tags: bash, centos7, netstat

I have coded a bash script to not show certain port when someone uses netstat. I have placed it in .bashrc file.

```sh
function test(){
    if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
       netstat | grep -v 1111;
    else
       netstat "$1" | grep -v 1111;
    fi
}
alias netstat='test'
```

When executed, sometimes when executing `netstat | grep 1111` (not always and it is not possible to specify in which situations) it creates an infinite number of grep processes.

The expected result is to return netstat output without the filtered port.

Comment: best to use a name other than `test` which is already on your system.Best to add `set -x` at the top of your function, then you'll have some better idea of what is happening. You can also turn on shell debugging in your terminal, with `set -x`. In either case, you can turn it off with `set +x`. Can't think why this would be happening with the code you have provided. It more likely something hidden (maybe related to `/bin/test`). Good luck.

Comment: Your requirement "not show certain port when someone uses netstat" is a little confusing. Your `function` based solution will only work when the `.bashrc` (or what ever file the function is included in) has be sourced. This will only affect the current session and can't impact another user's experience with `netstat` (without including the same function AND the function will have to be named `netstat` to override the original command.) Good luck.

Comment: The idea is to hide a port in netstat output. I know I can modify netstat source code and recompile it, but I guess this is a simple idea. I will try to set debug mode and see what could be happening. Thank you for your answers @shellter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for an alias, and you can use the `command` command to differentiate between your function `netstat` and the "real" command `netstat`.

```
netstat () {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        command netstat
    else
        command netstat "$1"
    fi | grep -v 1111
}
```

If your actual intention is to determine if there is an argument, rather than simply a non-empty argument (i.e., differentiate between `netstat` and `netstat ""`), you can reduce this (in `bash`) to

```
netstat () {
    command netstat "${@:1:1}" | grep -v 1111
}
```

The parameter expansion "disappears" if `$#` really is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is how your use of `netstat` is specified, without a full path.  So you get the recursion experienced.

I would suggest using something like `export NETSTAT=$(which netstat)`. Then your internal use can be based on the NETSTAT full path you have.